# How to calculate values to fill descriptive statistics table in one shot

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, broom

I have this dataset

```
    > dput(head(data, 130))
structure(list(ID = 1:130, Gender = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), format.spss = "F32.3", labels = c(Women = 1, 
Men = 2), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", "double")), 
    Education = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
    2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
    2, 2, 1, 1, 2), format.spss = "F32.3", labels = c(Basic = 1, 
    Medium = 2, Higher = 3), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
    "double")), Avoiding = structure(c(9, 10, 12, 10, 13, 11, 
    10, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 6, 9, 10, 9, 11, 9, 13, 11, 10, 10, 
    14, 13, 9, 8, 11, 7, 13, 6, 8, 10, 10, 9, 11, 8, 5, 8, 12, 
    9, 9, 11, 9, 10, 10, 8, 9, 9, 10, 8, 9, 8, 9, 10, 9, 14, 
    8, 5, 11, 5, 7, 14, 8, 11, 8, 9, 9, 8, 15, 9, 6, 8, 10, 9, 
    9, 10, 12, 8, 8, 8, 13, 8, 11, 9, 9, 5, 13, 8, 7, 10, 10, 
    12, 10, 5, 3, 9, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 16, 7, 10, 
    7, 7, 5, 4, 11, 16, 6, 9, 10, 10, 5, 9, 9, 7, 9, 12, 11, 
    10, 8, 10), format.spss = "F16.2"), Coping = structure(c(12, 
    8, 11, 12, 12, 8, 14, 5, 7, 12, 10, 15, 10, 7, 7, 7, 13, 
    7, 9, 12, 13, 11, 11, 15, 7, 5, 5, 10, 12, 13, 4, 8, 10, 
    8, 7, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 9, 7, 8, 8, 10, 9, 11, 7, 8, 10, 11, 
    6, 8, 10, 7, 9, 10, 10, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 9, 13, 8, 9, 11, 
    6, 6, 7, 8, 6, 13, 12, 9, 15, 11, 10, 10, 9, 8, 4, 13, 7, 
    6, 13, 9, 15, 12, 13, 11, 8, 8, 9, 12, 14, 12, 8, 11, 5, 
    9, 10, 9, 9, 12, 7, 11, 6, 13, 8, 9, 9, 5, 14, 16, 13, 10, 
    7, 14, 9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 13, 9, 14, 11, 14), format.spss = "F16.2"), 
    Obtaining = structure(c(15, 14, 17, 18, 16, 11, 20, 18, 11, 
    16, 19, 22, 20, 14, 15, 21, 19, 15, 16, 22, 19, 15, 18, 19, 
    20, 13, 16, 22, 20, 22, 20, 14, 15, 21, 13, 15, 14, 14, 18, 
    17, 19, 12, 12, 19, 17, 15, 14, 16, 18, 11, 17, 17, 15, 16, 
    11, 18, 13, 16, 12, 17, 15, 18, 21, 18, 18, 10, 14, 15, 15, 
    22, 16, 20, 14, 16, 21, 17, 14, 18, 11, 15, 15, 14, 12, 16, 
    16, 12, 7, 19, 16, 14, 16, 16, 14, 16, 15, 7, 16, 14, 12, 
    14, 15, 17, 16, 15, 15, 15, 13, 11, 7, 19, 17, 18, 16, 6, 
    20, 22, 14, 19, 19, 16, 18, 19, 12, 15, 18, 15, 16, 17, 13, 
    12), format.spss = "F16.2"), Savoring = structure(c(20, 22, 
    25, 21, 22, 11, 21, 19, 15, 18, 23, 24, 19, 20, 20, 22, 19, 
    24, 22, 22, 24, 19, 19, 25, 25, 22, 19, 16, 24, 24, 22, 17, 
    19, 23, 21, 19, 21, 23, 23, 24, 24, 16, 21, 21, 17, 19, 17, 
    22, 20, 15, 16, 21, 17, 18, 19, 21, 17, 18, 23, 21, 13, 17, 
    24, 14, 19, 21, 21, 19, 20, 24, 21, 20, 20, 20, 18, 22, 17, 
    16, 21, 18, 16, 18, 21, 16, 19, 19, 10, 23, 19, 16, 18, 14, 
    12, 18, 17, 7, 24, 15, 21, 16, 11, 17, 21, 17, 15, 21, 12, 
    14, 12, 14, 16, 16, 19, 19, 18, 19, 18, 14, 20, 15, 20, 19, 
    16, 18, 14, 18, 16, 20, 18, 16), format.spss = "F16.2"), 
    Efficacy = structure(c(24, 24, 29, 28, 29, 22, 30, 26, 16, 
    22, 26, 30, 32, 20, 24, 31, 28, 26, 25, 35, 30, 25, 28, 33, 
    33, 22, 24, 33, 27, 35, 26, 22, 25, 31, 22, 26, 22, 19, 26, 
    29, 28, 21, 23, 28, 27, 25, 22, 25, 27, 21, 25, 26, 23, 25, 
    21, 27, 27, 24, 17, 28, 20, 25, 35, 26, 29, 18, 23, 24, 23, 
    37, 25, 26, 22, 26, 30, 26, 24, 30, 19, 23, 23, 27, 20, 27, 
    25, 21, 12, 32, 24, 21, 26, 26, 26, 26, 20, 10, 25, 23, 17, 
    20, 22, 25, 23, 21, 23, 21, 20, 27, 14, 29, 24, 25, 23, 10, 
    31, 38, 20, 28, 29, 26, 23, 28, 21, 22, 27, 27, 27, 27, 21, 
    22), format.spss = "F16.2")), row.names = c(NA, -130L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(146:422, .Names = c("146", 
"147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", 
"156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", 
"165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", 
"174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", 
"183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", 
"192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", 
"201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", 
"210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", 
"219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", 
"228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", 
"237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", "245", 
"246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", "254", 
"255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", "263", 
"264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", "272", 
"273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", 
"282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", 
"291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", 
"300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", 
"309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", 
"318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", 
"327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", 
"336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", 
"345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", "353", 
"354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", 
"363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", 
"372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", "380", 
"381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", "389", 
"390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398", 
"399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", 
"408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
"417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422"), class = "omit"))
```

I got the value to fill it as you see here below.

```
data %>% 
  group_by(Education, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean = mean(Savoring), 
            sd = sd(Savoring)) %>% 
  mutate(tot_n = colSums(across(n)),
         tot_mean = colMeans(across(mean)), 
         tot_sd = colMeans(across(sd)))


data%>% 
  group_by(Education) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean = mean(Savoring), 
            sd = sd(Savoring))


data%>% 
  group_by(Gender) %>% 
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean = mean(Savoring), 
            sd = sd(Savoring))

mean(data$Savoring)
sd(data$Savoring)
```

Anyway, I do not know whether it is possible to do it by using just a unique chunk encoded in dplyr, but I was wondering whether there is a way to get such value differently without no typing different chunks of code as I did.

Could you just let me know, please?
Thanks

Comment: The table you are showing has nested headers, which is not possible in an R data frame. You would need column headers like `Means_Women`, `Means_Men`, `Means_total` etc. It would certainly be possible to do this with one big `summarize` call or by summarizing and pivoting to wide format. Difficult to show on your sample data, since the subset you provided only contains data for women.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to do. Using your dput data, can you show us what you expect your result data.frame to look like?

Comment: @AllanCameron I have integrated missing data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you are showing has nested headers, which is not possible in an R data frame. Instead, we can splice the gender name to the statistic name.

Using `tidyverse`, we can do this as follows:

```r
result <- data %>%
  mutate(Gender = names(attributes(Gender)$labels)[Gender],
         Education = names(attributes(Education)$labels[Education]),
         Education = factor(Education, c('Basic', 'Medium', 'Higher'))) %>%
  select(ID, Gender, Education, Savoring) %>%
  group_by(Education) %>%
  mutate(mean_total = mean(Savoring),
         sd_total = sd(Savoring),
         n_total = n()) %>%
  group_by(Education, Gender) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(Savoring),
            sd = sd(Savoring),
            n = n(),
            mean_total = mean(mean_total),
            sd_total = mean(sd_total),
            n_total = mean(n_total)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'Gender', values_from = mean:n) %>%
  select(c(1, 6, 5, 2, 8, 7, 3, 10, 9, 4)) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  bind_rows(data.frame(Education = 'Total', 
                       mean_Women = mean(data$Savoring[data$Gender == 1]),
                       mean_Men = mean(data$Savoring[data$Gender == 2]),
                       mean_total = mean(data$Savoring),
                       sd_Women = sd(data$Savoring[data$Gender == 1]),
                       sd_Men = sd(data$Savoring[data$Gender == 2]),
                       sd_total = sd(data$Savoring),
                       n_Women = sum(data$Gender == 1),
                       n_Men = sum(data$Gender == 2),
                       n_total = length(data$Savoring)))
```

Giving us

```
result
#>   Education mean_Women mean_Men mean_total sd_Women   sd_Men sd_total n_Women n_Men n_total
#> 1     Basic   19.50704 18.00000   19.38961 2.936826 1.264911 2.866117      71     6      77
#> 2    Medium   19.45455 16.38462   18.58696 3.800419 2.599310 3.745077      33    13      46
#> 3    Higher   10.66667 17.00000   14.28571 4.041452 2.449490 4.461475       3     4       7
#> 4     Total   19.24299 16.91304   18.83077 3.536444 2.314245 3.462173     107    23     130
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is a really great code. There is just a small issue left. As you could see there are also the 'Total' rows with grand means per each vertical group. Could you possibly suggest where a proper code should be put to return it in the final output?

Comment: @alias you would need to add a row manually at the end - see my update.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `data.table`'s powerful `groupingsets`, the one we use here is `cube`

```
library(data.table)

dat <- setDT(df)

# thanks to Allan Cameron for fixing the columns
dat[, Gender := names(attributes(Gender)$labels)[Gender]]
dat[, Education := names(attributes(Education)$labels[Education])]
dat[, Education := factor(Education, c('Basic', 'Medium', 'Higher'))]

# calculate the summary statistics including all sub and grand totals
out <- cube(dat, j = c(
  .(mean = lapply(.SD, mean)), 
  .(sd = lapply(.SD, sd)),
  .(n =.N)
), by = c("Education", "Gender"), .SDcols = "Savoring")

# replace the NA's for readable "total" names
out[is.na(Education), Education := "Total"][is.na(Gender), Gender := "total"]

# dcast to wide
dcast(out, Education ~ Gender, value.var = c("mean", "sd", "n"))
```

**same as above but nested**

```
dcast(
  cube(dat, 
    j = c(.(mean = lapply(.SD, mean)), .(sd = lapply(.SD, sd)), .(n =.N)), 
    by = c("Education", "Gender"), .SDcols = "Savoring"
  )[is.na(Education), Education := "Total"][is.na(Gender), Gender := "total"],
  Education ~ Gender, value.var = c("mean", "sd", "n")
)
```

**results**

```
   Education mean_Men mean_Women mean_total sd_Men sd_Women sd_total n_Men n_Women n_total
1:     Basic       18     19.507      19.39 1.2649   2.9368   2.8661     6      71      77
2:    Medium   16.385     19.455     18.587 2.5993   3.8004   3.7451    13      33      46
3:    Higher       17     10.667     14.286 2.4495   4.0415   4.4615     4       3       7
4:     Total   16.913     19.243     18.831 2.3142   3.5364   3.4622    23     107     130
```

Comment: wow really cool. I did not know this function

Comment: very impressive